# Multiple LTE modems. All the same MAC address

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, modem-manager

I'm trying to connect 4 Huawei ME909s-821 to my PC, to use it as a proxy

mmcli shows that all 4 are availible:

```
root@NanoPi-NEO-Core2:/home/pi# mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] ME909s-821
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/3 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] ME909s-821
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] ME909s-821
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/2 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] ME909s-821
```

but only one of them has `net` port and uses `option1, cdc_ether` drivers both:

```
 Hardware |      manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
           |             model: ME909s-821
           | firmware revision: 11.617.05.00.00
           |         supported: gsm-umts
           |           current: gsm-umts
           |      equipment id: 867223029944022
  -----------------------------
  System   |            device: /sys/devices/platform/soc/1c1b000.usb/usb3/3-1/3-1.2
           |           drivers: option1, cdc_ether
           |            plugin: Huawei
           |      primary port: ttyUSB7
           |             ports: ttyUSB5 (at), ttyUSB7 (at), wwx021e101f0000 (net),
           |                    ttyUSB8 (at)
```

Other modems use only `option1` driver and only have `ttyUSB*` ports.
As i can see, which modem will work properly is random. Avery boot it changes.
`ip addr` shows the same MAC addresses for all of them.

In `dmesg` i can see all of them initializes as wwan0, wwan1, wwan2 wwan3, but then for one of them happens this:

```
[    8.104760] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    8.485390] cdc_ether 3-1.2:2.0 wwx021e101f0000: renamed from wwan1
```

`wwx021e101f0000` is MAC based name, so I guess other devices skipped, because of the same MAC

So, question is
How to register otehr modems with `cdc_ether` driver or how to change MAC addresses of those modems?

Comment: Is it enough to give that modem a special device name so you can recognize it easier?